# Can a column contain sex information as ‘male’, ‘female’ and ‘total’ and still be tidy in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I am trying to make a dataset in R tidy. It contains many different variables with information on populations by year e.g. birth rate, death rate and so on. Most of this data is for the total population and not separated by sex. However, the values for the total population each year are separated by sex i.e. male population and female population. I’m thinking that sex should be its own column and population should be a column. But then I’m left with the other values that cannot be coded as male or female. So can my sex column have the levels: male, female and total? Or is it still a tidy data set if I leave the male and female population columns separate? If so, could I also have a total population column?

There is a lot of missing data so I’m not particularly concerned about the rows with missing data that would be created by adding a column for sex. I just need to be sure the data conforms to a ‘tidy’ format.

I have successfully created a data set in each way as described above but I’m concerned which one can be considered tidy. I’m not looking for advice on the code itself.

Comment: So in your proposed data, you'd have 3 rows for each year: male, female, and total, but all the values (except for population) would be NA for the male and female rows – is that right? If I'm understanding correctly, this sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Yes that would be correct. 

Would it be considered tidy if I just kept the male, female and total population columns?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So in your proposed data, you'd have 3 rows for each year: male, female, and total, but all the values (except for population) would be NA for the male and female rows – is that right?

**Your proposal, with sex pivoted longer**

| year | sex | population | gdp | esc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | M | 300 | *NA* | *NA* |
| 2000 | F | 230 | *NA* | *NA* |
| 2000 | Total | 530 | 3452 | 454 |

Versus the **original wide form data**:

| year | male_pop | female_pop | total_pop | gdp | esc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 300 | 230 | 530 | 3452 | 454 |

If I'm understanding correctly, this sounds like a bad idea. I think you're being a bit overzealous with the "rules" of tidy data and actually making things more messy. [In Hadley Wickham's paper, the criteria of tidy data is](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html#:%7E:text=Tidy%20data%20is%20a%20standard,Every%20row%20is%20an%20observation.):

> In **tidy data**:
>
> 1. Every column is a variable.
> 2. Every row is an observation.
> 3. Every cell is a single value.

In the wide form data, each row is an observation (the data for the year) and while technically having 3 columns for population by sex is not a big deal since and saves you from the messy proposed setup.

Think about how you'd use the data - what would be gained from the different format? It is larger, less clear, and you have to deal with NA and do additional operations to analyze it.

If you really want to make your data tidy and avoid the repeated sex-specific population columns (You might do this if there were more than just one set of sex-specific variables), you should pivot the *entire* table into long form, not just part of it.

Full **long form data**:

| year | sex | stat | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | M | pop | 300 |
| 2000 | F | pop | 230 |
| 2000 | Total | pop | 530 |
| 2000 | Total | gdp | 3452 |
| 2000 | Total | esc | 454 |